# VBA to check if a cell with formula has been overwritten and refill the cell with original formula

Tags: excel, vba

Like in the title. 
I have a column that need to be able to take either a manual input number or if none is given, return the value of a function. I know I can use one extra column but since there are already 50 columns in the file I'd rather not to. 
So what I'm looking for is a vba sub that can run automatically to check if a cell in a certain column has manual data and if that data is cleared then put the original function back in, an event triggered sub basically.

Comment: Just set all cells to "Unlocked", then "Lock" all cells with formulas and protect the sheet. This would prevent users from accidentally delete formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Use a worksheet_change event triggered on column A. If the Target is blank, put a formula in.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bye
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
            'Debug.Print t.Value
            If t.Value = vbNullString Then
                t.FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(RC2:RC8)"  '=SUM(B2:H2) in row 2
            End If
        Next t
    End If
bye:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```